# How to use Blockchain to store government records and secure transactions between government and users and also between 2 users?

Tags: database, blockchain, ethereum

I would like to implement a simple prototype of this for my local government which has a lot of corrupt and lazy government officials. I feel it would really speed things up and make sure there are no scams in records, of which there are many atm. I have seen many big cities implementing blockchain.
I'm a computer science student and an android and web programmer and I've bought a few technical books on blockchain. But I'm not sure how to go about doing something like this.

Is something like this really going to be feasible and secure from hackers? I don't wanna make things worse.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you are planning to use a blockchain as a database to keep the records regarding lands, vehicles, government services etc. to avoid making illegal changes by the government officials themselves or some other third party.

To get the advantage of having a distributed database, in an application like yours especially, the blockchain should be a public one. (Rather than few government institutes running full nodes ). In that case as per your need of only protecting records it might probably be a separate blockchain for the particular purpose. And probably there should be an advantage for the participants for them to participate in mining consuming their resources. I think then you have to come up with a economic model as well. (although if this is not the exact way you are gonna do there have to be reason for ppl to participate somehow)

And regarding how secure the system will be; that depends on your model. If it's going to be a blockchain with few nodes or even let's say public with a large no of nodes and if it's still worth the money to spend on attacking the network and acquiring one or two lands there can be situations that the network may under go [51% attack](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/51-attack.asp) or a [selfish mining](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/selfish-mining-a-25-attack-against-the-bitcoin-network-1383578440/) attack.

So what I can suggest is to study more on blockchain, consensus algorithms used, how existing blockchains achieve the data security etc. and think about a model (may be an economic model) that the miners get an advantage by running the node, and the cost to attack the system outweigh the advantages that can be gained by attacking etc.